# Methods to find the value of $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{z+e^{it}}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|z|\neq1$, what are the classic methods to determine the value of:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{z+e^{it}}$$

I thought of rewriting the integral with only real integrands but it seems very tedious. I am not asking necessarily for an answer but I would like to know how can I approach this kind of integral in order to be quite efficient.

I never saw contour integration, so I am not going to use it in any case. But if you have a solution that involves this concept, I would be glad to read it anyway.

Comment: It pretty much has to be done by, if not contour integration, then at least a method that understands why the answer is in general non-zero despite the obvious antiderivative $\frac{i}{z}\ln|1+ze^{-it}|$.

Comment: If you multiply the integrand by $1=\frac{e^{-it}}{e^{-it}}$, then your integrand is a logarithmic derivative

Comment: @Sal Yes, this is what J.G. made me realize. But then I can't use the same result as for real-valued function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand integrand as a power series in $z$ or $z^{-1}$ depends on whether $|z| < 1$ or $> 1$.
$$\frac{1}{z+ e^{it}} = 
\begin{cases}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-z)^n e^{-i(n+1)t},&|z| < 1\\
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-e^{it})^n z^{-(n+1)},&|z| > 1
\end{cases}$$

Since $|z^n e^{-i(n+1)t}| = |z|^n$ and $|e^{int}z^{-(n+1)}| = |z|^{-(n+1)}$,
the magnitude of the functions in the expansion is bounded by a geometric series in $|z|$ or $|z|^{-1}$ and independent of $t$.

From this, it is easy to deduce the series of functions converges uniformly over $[0,2\pi]$ and hence we can integrate it term by term.... The rest is straight forward.

Comment: Thank you. I love this approach.

Comment: Neat. You’ve essentially found the Fourier series for the integrated, and then the integral is $2\pi$ times the constant term.

Answer (score 1):

**Large Hint:** It is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{i}\int_\gamma \frac{w^{-1}\,dw}{z+w}$$ where $\gamma(t)=e^{it}.$

Then $$\frac{w^{-1}}{w+z}=\frac1{w(w+z)}=\frac{1}{z}\left(\frac1w-\frac1{w+z}\right)$$

Then the integral depends on whether $|z|<1$ or $|z|>1.$

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It seems that contour integration is very adapted to deal with this kind of integrals. If you have suggestions to keep real notations for the limits of integration, I would highly appreciate it! In other words, I am wondering if there is a way to bypass the $\int_{\gamma}$ notation?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=|z|e^{ia}$ and rewrite the integral

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{dt}{z+e^{it}}
= e^{-i a}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|z| +\cos (t-a) -i \sin (t-a)}{|z| ^2+ 2|z|\cos (t-a)+1}dt
$$
where the integration over the $\sin$-term vanishes due to periodicity. Integrate  the remaining  integrand as follows

\begin{align}
I= &\frac{1}{2z}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(1+ \frac{|z| ^2-1}{|z| ^2+ 2|z|\cos t+1}\right)\>dt\\
=& \frac{1}{z}\left( \pi+ {(|z|^2-1})\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d(\tan\frac t2)}{(|z|-1)^2\tan^2\frac t2+(|z| +1)^2}dt\right)\\
=& \frac\pi z \left( 1+\text{sgn}\left(  \frac{|z|+1}{|z|-1}\right)\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{z+e^{it}}~~~~(1)$$
Apply** $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{z+e^{-it}}~~~~(2)$$
Then add the two results to get
$$2I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2z+2\cos t}{z^2+2z\cos t+1}$$
Next use
$\int_{0}^{2a} f(x) dx=2\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx, ~if~ f(2a-x)=f(x)$.
Then we get$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{2z+2\cos t}{z^2+2z\cos t+1}dt=\frac{1}{z} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1+2z\cos t}+\frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^{\pi} dt$$
Next use the standard integral $$J=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{A+\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{A^2-1}}, A>1$$
We get $$I=\frac{2\pi}{z}$$

Edit: Finding $J$ use ** again to get $$2J=\int_{0}^{\pi} \left(\frac{1}{A+\cos x}+\frac{1}{A-\cos x}\right) dx=2A\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sec^2x dx}{A^2(1+\tan^2x) +A^2-1}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{A^2-1}}.$$ By taking $\tan x=u$.

Comment: I think that value only works for $|z|>1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, with $z=0$  we clearly have that the integral equals $0$.

Comment: Yes, the other answers have the integral is $0$ for all $|z|<1.$ (Well, neither other answer actually gives values, but when you work them out...)

Comment: Sorry, $-1$ because this is wrong if $|z|<$ and I can’t figure out why it is right for $|z|>1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for looking so thoroughly into the answers. It seems that the calculation of $I$ before the use of $J$ is correct. It is not clear at all for me how $J$ was used to calculate $I$, moreover $J$ takes a *real* parameter greater than $1$... Therefore I think this answer needs further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite
$$\frac{1}{z+e^{i t}}=\frac{1}{z}-\frac{e^{i t}}{z \left(z+e^{i t}\right)}$$
$$\int\frac{1}{z+e^{i t}} \,dt=\frac{t}{z}+\frac{i \log \left(z+e^{i t}\right)}{z}$$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{z+e^{i t}} \,dt=\frac {2 \pi}z$$

Comment: Thank you. But it does not hold for $|z|<1$, could you provide an explanation of why it could work for $|z|>1$ please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the mean value theorem for harmonic functions:

$$f\left( z \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{f\left( z+{{e}^{it}} \right)dt}\Rightarrow \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi }{\frac{1}{z+{{e}^{it}}}dt}=\frac{2\pi }{z}$$

This is true for all z where f is analytic in a unit circle centred at z. For example this is true for all z with $\operatorname{Re}\left( z \right)>1$ etc.